# How much memory does one stack of a recursive call in Java take?

Tags: java, memory, stack

How much memory does a stack of a recursive call take? What does it depend on, and how do I find the exact amount of memory used by a particular recursive stack in Java

Comment: I'll assume you mean stack frame?  Depends on how many variables you put on your stack.

Comment: Yes, I mean stack frame. Is there any method in java I can use to calculate how much memory is used by a particular stack frame?

Comment: No, there is not.  Why do you think you want one?

Comment: I'm doing a comparison on the space complexity of a recursive merge sort and an iterative merge sort. Is there any way I can manually calculate/approximate the amount of memory used by the stack frame of a recursive call, based on the parameters of the recursive function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A strack frame contains:

- a return address
- a base pointer
- enough space for all the parameters and local variables that are declared in the method concerned, remembering that object-valued variables are references to objects, not objects.

This is almost always trivial.

There is no method in Java (at least short of the debugger API) that will tell you.

Comment: Is there any way I can manually calculate/approximate the amount of memory used by the stack frame of a recursive call, based on the parameters of the recursive function?

Comment: Sure, just add up their widths. Easy.

Comment: What do you mean add up their widths?

Comment: The number of memory words that they occupy.

Comment: For example, a Java integer is 32 bits wide, or 4 bytes; short=2 bytes, long=4, object reference=4.